# Convert FL Studio time to just Ticks

Tags: conversion, fl-studio, format

I need to convert FL's `bar/step:tick` to just `ticks`.
The end of the song as FL shows it is `42:04:095`
but in just ticks it is `64416`.

I need the tick number to use a external program.

Also, is there a way to insert controllers with specific parameters?

I'm using FL Studio 11.

Comment: What's FL's tick resolution? 480 ppq? If so, & assuming your 42:04:095 is bar:beat:tick, it's (42*[#of beats in a bar, presumably 4]*480) + (4*480) + 95

Comment: how would i find the resolution? the tempo is 150 BPM, notes per beat is 8. does it have anything to do with that?

Comment: ok, i found it with the external program, its 384

Comment: @Tetsujin ok, i'll add your comment as the answer. btw thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tetsujin for formula

The basic formula is (**Bar** X **Beats per Bar** X **Tick Resolution**) + (**Beats** X **Tick Resolution**) + **Remaining FL Ticks** = **Ticks**